What motivates using space of homogeneous polynomials in two complex variables for representations of SU(2)?
I'm working through Hall's Lie Groups book and he introduces the irreducible representations of SU(2) by considering spaces of homogeneous polynomials in two complex variables.
While this leads to a very clean classification of the irreducible representations of sl2(C), he doesn't say a word about what would motivate considering such a space. Why is this a natural candidate for a representation, other than the fact that it turns out to be nice? What motivates its use?

Here are two answers, one algebraic and one geometric.

In the algebraic approach, there are a well-understood family of operations which produce new representations of a group from old representations, e.g. taking duals and tensor products. Homogeneous polynomials in two complex variables of degree $n$ corresponds to the $n^{th}$ symmetric power $S^n(V)$ of the defining representation $V = \mathbb{C}^2$ of $SU(2)$ (strictly speaking, to the symmetric power of the dual, but $V$ is self-dual so this doesn't matter much). This is an operation we can perform on any representation of any group, although it won't always be irreducible. But, for example, the $n^{th}$ symmetric power $S^n(\mathbb{C}^d)$ of the defining representation of $SU(d)$ is irreducible for $d \ge 2$ and all $n$.
$SU(2)$ is particularly nice, and in this particularly nice case we can show that these are all irreducible representations. In general we have to work harder; one way to describe the answer involves Schur-Weyl duality and Schur functors, or we could use the language of highest weights.

In the geometric approach we ask ourselves, generally: if we have a group $G$ how might we construct representations of it? The easiest representation to construct is variations of the regular representation, namely $G$ acting on functions on $G$. What "functions" means depends on what kind of a group $G$ is; here since $SU(2)$ is compact we can consider the regular representation on $L^2(SU(2))$ with respect to Haar measure. We can always do this sort of thing but it's not clear a priori how to cut this very large representation down into irreducibles.
A refinement of this approach is that if $G$ acts on another space $X$, then it also acts on functions on $X$. For example if $X = G/H$ where $H$ is a subgroup this gives us a representation on, say, $L^2(G/H)$ (if $G/H$ is well-behaved enough to also have a Haar measure); this is a geometric way of thinking about induced representations, specifically the induction of the trivial representation of $H$ to a representation of $G$. $SU(2)$ happens to act on a very nice space, namely the complex projective line $\mathbb{CP}^1$, also known as the Riemann sphere. So it also acts on, say, $L^2(\mathbb{CP}^1)$. But again it's not clear how to cut this down into irreducibles. (This also turns out to miss half of the irreducibles because the action of $SU(2)$ on $\mathbb{CP}^1$ is not faithful but factors through the double cover to $SO(3)$.)
To get from here to homogeneous polynomials requires that we make two additional modifications to this idea:

First we can ask, what if we try to induce a nontrivial representation from $H$ to $G$? Geometrically, if we begin with a $1$-dimensional representation $\chi$ of $H$, this produces an object on $G/H$ called an equivariant line bundle $L_{\chi}$, and then $G$ acts on the space of sections of $L_{\chi}$. This is a geometric version of the induction of $\chi$ to $G$.
Second, if we try to apply this idea to $\mathbb{CP}^1$ we find that we get not only equivariant line bundles on $\mathbb{CP}^1$ but holomorphic, or equivalently algebraic, line bundles, and so we can consider holomorphic, or equivalently algebraic, sections of those bundles. Skipping a lot of details, performing this construction in this case produces the space of homogeneous polynomials of degree $n$ as the space of holomorphic / algebraic sections of an equivariant line bundle on $\mathbb{CP}^1$ called $O(n)$, the $n^{th}$ Serre twisting sheaf.

This is a sketch of the Borel-Weil theorem applied to $SU(2)$. This is of course much more complicated and requires a lot more background than the algebraic approach, but this geometric approach, which goes by the general name geometric representation theory, connects to interesting generalizations and related ideas, and I think with enough of the relevant background is a pretty good answer to the question of how to find "natural candidates" for representations. This construction can also be understood as a form of geometric quantization.
